# What does this Java Syntax mean?

Tags: java, hadoop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the <TYPE> in java mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649572/what-does-the-type-in-java-mean)

In the code below, what does Iterator`<V>` and OutputCollector`<K, V>` mean? Is it a special data type?

```
public void reduce(K key, 
  Iterator<V> values, 
  OutputCollector<K, V> output, 
  Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
```

Comment: Those are Generic types.  Check out the tutorial, it is really helpful. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html

Comment: Sort of. Those are generic types: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Answer (score 2):

K stands for Key and V for Value, like in a HashMap. There isn't a Key class or a Value class that you have to instantiate or subclass, it's a semantic thing for generics. Those letters are only placeholders for whatever classes you decide should fill the Key and Value roles.