# What does the <TYPE> in java mean?

Tags: java, syntax

I have seen declarations, interfaces and classes that go `TYPE<CLASS>`

What does this do/mean?

Comment: @MadProgrammer probably generic types ??

Comment: You must be referring to [bounded types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html), which is part of Java's [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Comment: public interface Grid<E>

Comment: ArrayList<Location> getValidAdjacentLocations(Location loc);

Comment: Nitpick: they're parameterized types (not necessarily with bounded type parameters).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Without evidence, I believe you're talking about [Java's Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/intro.html) support...

> Generics allow you to abstract over types

Before Java 5 it was difficult to provide classes that were capable of supporting multiple different types of Objects without having to code for each specific situation, so it was common for people to pass `Object` instead.

This leads to many difficult choices to make at runtime, you'd have to do a runtime check to see if it was possible to cast a given Object to a usable type...for example

```
List myIntList = new LinkedList(); // 1
myIntList.add(new Integer(0)); // 2
Integer x = (Integer) myIntList.iterator().next(); // 3
```

Now, this is reasonably obvious, but if you were passed just a `List`, you'd have to check each and every element in the list for correctness...

But now, we can do this...

```
List<Integer> myIntList = new LinkedList<Integer>(); // 1'
myIntList.add(new Integer(0)); // 2'
Integer x = myIntList.iterator().next(); // 3'
```

This is a contract that basically says "This list only contains Integer type's of objects".

With generics you can construct a single class that is capable of handling multiple different data types or a family of data types (ie constraint the parameter so that it must be extended from a particular parent type).

```
Iterator<? extends Number> itNum;
```

Basically says, this will contain objects that inherit from `Number`, include `Integer`, `Long`, `Double`, `Float`...

Often in method and class decelerations you will see something similar to...

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> {...}
```

or

```
public class MyGenericClass<T extends MyBaseObject> {...}
```

This allows you to refer to `T` as if it were a concrete object type, for example...

```
public class MyGenericClass<T extends MyBaseObject> {
    private T value;
    public MyGenericClass(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

This allows the compiler (and JVM) to essentially "replace" the marker `T` with a concert type (okay, it's a little more complicated then that, but that's the magic)...

This allows to do things like...

```
... new MyGenericClass<MySuperObject>(new MySuperObject());
... new MyGenericClass<MySuperSuperObject>(new MySuperSuperObject());
```

And know that it will only ever accept the type of object I specify...

Have a read through the link in the first paragraph, I'm sure it can do more justice then I can ;)

Comment: (Maybe your wording is just different that i would have) List<? extends Number> means that you don't know the exact parameter type, only that it extends Number.  This could mean List<Integer>, List<Double>, etc...  By declaring a variable like this, it's impossible for the compiler to tell what the real type will be.  As a result calling methods like "add" will cause compile errors (go ahead and try it out).  Collections declared this way are usable mostly for iteration.  List<Number> however can contain any object which is a Number subclass.

Answer (score 9):

```
public class Grid<E> {
```

That's how you define a generic class in Java.`Grid` is the class and `E` is a formal type parameter.

If you are really interested in learning about it, you will find a very good reference here - [Java Generics FAQs - Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

Answer (score 3):

that is generic types [check it here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).
 Simple examples would be

```
List<String>

Map<Integer, String>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you are asking without looking at what exactly you are seeing. But it's likely you are seeing Generics in Java. [Learn more about it here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

The idea is basically to make stronger type-safety in Java. So, a declaration like `List<Integer> intList` means `intList` has Integers in it. And if you try to put a, say, String -- it will throw compilation error.