# What does class<P> mean in Java?

Tags: java, generics, class-template

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the <TYPE> in java mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649572/what-does-the-type-in-java-mean)

Hello I came across this class while debugging , can someone give me pointers to what it means, please. Thanks.

```
class Something<P>{
 private P someVariable;
}

//what does <P> mean here?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a generic.  It allows you to write code that works with different types.

Try this tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of class templating (although it is erased at runtime). Usually it is class and not class

. It allows you to inject a type into a class at compile time.

For example if you did

```
new Something<String>();
```

then the someVariable would be of type String.

If you called

```
new Something();
```

then I believe someVariable would be of type Object as it would have no inferred type information. Usually your IDE will give you a warning about this.

It is also described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Generic_class_definitions).

Comment: This isn't quite correct.  The type of the generic is erased at runtime.  Generics only impact the type safety check at compile time.

Comment: @MelNicholson Agreed on the erasure - but what part of my answer says that it is not erased? Feel free to update to make it a better answer - I may not have expressed myself clearly enough. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It means its a generic class.
You create a generic type declaration by changing the code

```
  "public class Box" to "public class Box<T>"
```

For further information you can see this reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Answer (score 2):

`P` is a type used for generics.

Usually it is `T`, or `TEntity`, for type or entity type.

Just think of `ArrayList<string>` as an example where the type is `string`.

Answer (score 2):

```
This is a Generic class definition.

<P> is the place holder for an Object that get substituted at compile.
```